# Panorama is blurred by three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, krpano

I made a panorama using three.js in the mobile but its blurred. I also tried to use krpano and the effect is ok.

here is an image with three.js effect：[three.js](http://dev-img.mankuhome.com/testPano/threeJS.JPG)
here is one in [krpano](http://dev-img.mankuhome.com/testPano/krpano.JPG)

I know to use `renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)`, but it is still blurred

I expect the effect in the three.js like in the krpano

Comment: What is the resolution of your panorama texture? Can you share some code that shows how you create your panorama? A [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/) is even better.

Comment: ok, three.js: https://dev-admin.mankuhome.com/test/index.html
krpano: https://dev-admin.mankuhome.com/test2/tour.html

Comment: here is a demo:https://jsfiddle.net/4batsdg2/5/

Comment: plz give me some advice.thank you very much!!!

Comment: Sry, I honestly think that the `three.js` demo looks okay. `krpano` seems to use a totally different approach for rendering the panorama view. So comparing both demos is not really meaningful.

Comment: emmmm,so can i change the texture type and format to improve the effect? i like three.js and i dont want to give up. can i do something else to improve the effect in the  three.js.thank you very much!!!

Comment: Sry, I don't know that. I guess you need somebody with special knowledge about rendering techniques in context of panoramas.